# Increment value (likeCount) inside Entity without running into concurrency problems

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Example:

**PostEntity**

```
public class PostEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 567999999736566810L;

    @Id
    private String uid;

    // Value to be incremented
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int likeCount = 0;



    // ... Getters and Setters
}
```

**Inside PostService**

```
public int likePost(String postUID) {
    final PostEntity postEntity = postRepository.findByUid(postUID);
    int update = postEntity.getLikeCount() + 1;
    postEntity.setLikeCount(update);
    postRepository.save(postEntity);
    return update;
}
```

**Main Question:**
How would this be implemented in such a way to avoid collisions?
Like two users getting the value 6 and incrementing it to 7. Instead of the desired result of 8.
I've seen it done in JS using MongoDB.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a transaction with `SERIALIZABLE` isolation. Mark your service method using `@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)` to ensure no 2 concurrent processes are executing this transaction.

This [Bealdung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-transactional-propagation-isolation#5-serializable-isolation) article explains the different types of isolation and propagation.

Comment: Again thank you for the help! It worked well but only with 2 incoming requests. Once the 3rd request hit it through a `MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction`.  Any idea as to the reason why? Again Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Hmm and that said, you'll probably need a lock on the `findByUid` method too (a `for update`) indicating that you'll want to update the row. You can do this by marking the `repository` method with a `@Lock` annotation, like so : `@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_READ)`. Might be best to have a separate repo method for this since a pessimistic lock will always require a transaction to be active.

Refer to https://www.baeldung.com/java-jpa-transaction-locks for more information about locking.